# Datasets for Causal Inference with Continuous Covariates

Tags: data-request, randomized-trial

I am interested in testing a causal inference and need a dataset with the explanatory variables mostly or, even better, all continuous; ideally a randomized control setting, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Challenges in Machine Learning](http://www.chalearn.org/)

Here you can find [causality Workbench](http://www.causality.inf.ethz.ch/repository.php?page=data) datasets Choose the one that matches your requirement. Most of the datasets were from the competitions or from the real-world data.